# How to calculate the weight of an edge wth a custom function in janusgraph?

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph, weighted

So we the following graph in Janusgraph:

```
g.addV().property('nameV',   'source').as('1').
  addV().property('nameV', 'destiny2').as('2').
  addV().property('nameV', 'destiny4').as('3').
  addE('connects').from('1').to('2').property('nameE', 'edge1').property('bw', 2000).property('latency', 100).
  addE('connects').from('2').to('3').property('nameE', 'edge2').property('bw',  100).property('latency', 200).
  addE('connects').from('1').to('3').property('nameE', 'edge3').property('bw', 3000).property('latency', 500).iterate();
```

and this query gives me the shortest path between two nodes using the **bandwidth (bw)** as the weight of each edge along the path:

```
g.V().has('nameV', 'source').repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).until(has('nameV', 'destiny4')).
  path().as('p').  
  by(coalesce(values('bw'), constant(0.0))).
  map(unfold().sum()).as('xyz').
  select('p', 'xyz').
  order().by('xyz', asc).limit(1).
  next();
```

what I need is a way to calculate the weight of each edge (at query-time) with a custom function that uses edges´s parameters, like: 100*bw/latency

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine a `sack` and the `math` step to do this all in Gremlin

```
gremlin> g.withSack(0).
......1>   V().has('nameV', 'source').
......2>   repeat(outE().
......3>          sack(sum).
......4>            by(project('bw','lat').
......5>              by('bw').
......6>              by('latency').
......7>              math('100*bw/lat')).
......8>          inV().
......9>          simplePath()).
.....10>   until(has('nameV', 'destiny4')).
.....11>   order().
.....12>     by(sack(),desc).
.....13>   path()

==>[v[0],e[6][0-connects->2],v[2],e[7][2-connects->4],v[4]]
==>[v[0],e[8][0-connects->4],v[4]]
```

UPDATED (EXPANDED):

To change the result to include the calculated value and perhaps also the individual values along the way for `bw` you can combine the `path` and the `sack` inside a `union` step. The `local` step is used so that the `fold` is applied to each path individually and not all of the paths.

```
gremlin> g.withSack(0).
......1>   V().has('nameV', 'source').
......2>   repeat(outE().
......3>          sack(sum).
......4>            by(project('bw','lat').
......5>              by('bw').
......6>              by('latency').
......7>              math('100*bw/lat')).
......8>          inV().
......9>          simplePath()).
.....10>   until(has('nameV', 'destiny4')).
.....11>   order().
.....12>     by(sack(),desc).
.....13>   local(
.....14>     union(
.....15>       path().
.....16>         by('nameV').
.....17>         by(valueMap('bw','latency')),
.....18>       sack()).
.....19>       fold())  

==>[[source,[bw:2000,latency:100],destiny2,[bw:100,latency:200],destiny4],2050.0]
==>[[source,[bw:3000,latency:500],destiny4],600.0]
```

Comment: I added to the answer to show the result being included.

Comment: Perfect mr. Kelvin. Great book by the way!